# Helidon 4 and Http API

Tags: java, helidon, virtual-threads, nima

in Helidon 3 and earlier versions there a **io.helidon.common.http** package
https://helidon.io/docs/v3/apidocs/io.helidon.common.http/io/helidon/common/http/package-summary.html

But in Helidon 4 there is a **io.helidon.http** package instead
https://helidon.io/docs/v4/apidocs/io.helidon.http/io/helidon/http/package-summary.html

1. Is this new http package a replacement for the common.http package
   and should all use of io.helidon.common.http be migrated to
   io.helidon.http if we are going to uptake Helidon 4?
2. Is this new package the result of Helidon use of virtual threads (i.e. Níma
   )?

Comment: Have you checked the [upgrade guide](https://helidon.io/docs/v4/se/guides/upgrade_4x)?

Comment: I found no mention of io.helidon.common.http there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this new http package a replacement for the common.http package

It looks like yes, it is. If you look at Níma Maven artefact

```
<groupId>io.helidon.nima.webserver</groupId>
<artifactId>helidon-nima-webserver</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-M1</version>
```

then you'll find there helidon-common-http-4.0.0-M1.jar with `io.helidon.common.http` package in it which is almost (sic!) a full copy of `io.helidon.http` in helidon-http-4.0.4.jar.

But not a drop-in replacement! Looks like Helidon authors couldn't care less of such trifles as portability. Although few classes like `Forwarded` were moved from `io.helidon.common.http` to `io.helidon.http` "as-is", some other were reshuffled: for example, `Http.Status` was moved a separate `Status`.

> Is this new package the result of Helidon use of virtual threads (i.e. Níma )

Only indirectly so. If, as the [Helidon manual](https://helidon.io/docs/v4/about/intro) says, the major jump from 3 to 4 is a replacement of asynchronous ("reactive") calls with blocking ones:

Helidon 3

```
request.content().as(JsonObject.class)
        .thenAccept(jo -> doSomething(jo, response));
```

Helidon 4

```
doSomething(request.content().as(JsonObject.class), response);
```

it is indeed a gigantic jump, but it does not warrant, to my understanding, such reshuffling of quite innocent, utility-like package as `io.helidon.common.http`. Rather, a result of cowboy approach to portability and versions compatibility.

A word of warning: If you are going to migrate to virtual threads on your production, please be aware of some virtual threads-related deadlock/hanging issues, discussed in Stack Overflow, most reproducible of them is [Java Virtual threads and ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861482/java-virtual-threads-and-concurrenthashmap) and especially a case discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77866249/2366397).

Comment: Thanks for your insight igor.zh, it was most helpful

Comment: You are absolutely welcome. Good luck with virtual threads. Keep SO in touch in a case of deadlocks/hangs.